# Get number of products per page in Shopify

Tags: javascript, php, shopify, shopify-template

I want to show items on current page out of total items in collections but i am not able to fetch the total no. of products on current page.

```
<div class="productcount">{{ products_per_page }} out of {{ collection.products_count }} products</div>
```

Comment: Please share the sample code.

Comment: provided above is enough

Comment: Can you please include the `{% paginate %}` tags that you're using in your example?

Comment: I do not want a pagination, i already have Load more button there. I just want to display the no. of products on current page

Answer (score 0):

A collections page [shows up to 50 products](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/tags/theme-tags#paginate). So if you do not paginate, the total number of products will be collection.products_count if its less then 50, or 50 otherwise.

If you do paginate, then the number of products will be [paginate.page_size](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/paginate#paginate-page_size).